# How to properly do date logic in Ruby / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I have a need to read a date as a UTC unix timestamp integer. And then use it, do some date calculations on it.

I wrote a rails application and a spec that mimicks my environment.

https://github.com/dlikhten/semaphoretests/blob/master/spec/time/test_time.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "time testing" do
  base_time = Time.new("2012")

  8760.times do |n|
    context "#{n + 1} hour offset" do
      let(:now) { base_time + (n + 1).hours }
      before { Timecop.freeze(now) }
      after { Timecop.return }

      it do
        # puts now.to_s

        t1 = 30.days.from_now.utc.to_i

        # puts t1

        d1 = Time.at(t1).to_date

        # puts d1

        d2 = 30.days.from_now.to_date

        # puts d2
        # puts 30.days.from_now.to_date

        d1.should == 30.days.from_now.to_date
        d2.should == 30.days.from_now.to_date
        d1.should == d2
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Can anyone tell me why this spec fails? This tries running the logic for every hour of the year. At some hours it fails.

What's interesting is that I get a 1-day off calculation a few times a day. Makes no sense why this happens. Notice that I do Timecop.freeze to ensure that all dates generated are identical timestamps.

In theory it should already operate on the correct timezone in all instances.

Ruby 1.9.2
Rails 3.2.6

Comment: What about memory? Maybe this construction consumes a lot of memory?

Comment: What does mean Timecop.return? return is keyword and it can't be a method

Comment: @megas `return` *can* be used as a method name, as long as it's always called with an explicit receiver.

Comment: `Timecop.return` stops timecop's hijacking. So `Timecop.freeze` makes all calls to get the current time frozen to the given time, `Timecop.travel` will make the current time the given time, but it moves forward.

Comment: Memory not an issue. This consumes nothing AND fails about 30% of the tests. Not all at the end, mind you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `to_i` with `to_f`.

It's possible that the fractional second truncation is making a difference. Not sure why it would though.

Or, instead of calling `to_f` in the loop, for better performance chop off the fraction from the `base_time`:

```
base_time = Time.at(Time.new('2012').to_i)
```